# Query to fetch data from given date to 48 hrs in amazon red shift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Using the data in redshift we need to understand the numbers of id's who shop on one platform and purchase on another digital platform within 48 hours.

Each platform have a seperate fact table and user id is common in all the tables.

I am trying to use the below code but no use. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Select Distinct a.id ,
b.login AndroidLogin,
c.login iPadLogin,
d.login iPhoneLogin,
e.login MobileLogin,
f.login WebLogin
from
users a inner join
fct_android_20160101_20160331 b 
on a.id = b.userid 
inner join  
fct_ipad_20160101_20160331 c 
on a.id = c.userid
inner join
fct_iphone_20160101_20160331 d 
on a.id = d.userid
inner join
fct_mobilepolaris_20160101_20160331 e 
on a.id = e.userid
inner join
fct_polaris_20160101_20160331 f
on a.id = f.userid
where (b.date between '2016-01-01' and dateadd(day,2,date))
or (c.date between '2016-01-01' and dateadd(day,2,date)) 
or (d.date between '2016-01-01' and dateadd(day,2,date))
or (e.date between '2016-01-01' and dateadd(day,2,date)) 
or (f.date between '2016-01-01' and dateadd(day,2,date))
and id > 0 
and id <> 'null'
 and length(Id) = 10 
 and LEFT(Id,1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
order by 1
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `LEFT JOIN` the tables. Doing a regular `JOIN` means that you will retrieve only those `id`s that bought something on all platforms in the period. Doing that and cleaning up the format you get, the rather more readable:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,
                b.login AndroidLogin,
                c.login iPadLogin,
                d.login iPhoneLogin,
                e.login MobileLogin,
                f.login WebLogin
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN fct_android_20160101_20160331 b       ON a.id = b.userid AND b.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'
LEFT JOIN fct_ipad_20160101_20160331 c          ON a.id = c.userid AND c.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'
LEFT JOIN fct_iphone_20160101_20160331 d        ON a.id = d.userid AND d.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'
LEFT JOIN fct_mobilepolaris_20160101_20160331 e ON a.id = e.userid AND e.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'
LEFT JOIN fct_polaris_20160101_20160331 f       ON a.id = f.userid AND f.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'
WHERE length(a.id) = 10 
  AND left(a.id,1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the clarification. Can you please help to see if a user have logged on one platform and made a purchase on another within 48hrs. For example if id 'a' have logged on to android on 01-01-2016 i want to write a query if same id have used any other platform in 2days.Hope i made it clear. I am new user and would need some help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The general approach would be to `UNION` the 5 tables for the platforms and then `SELECT DISTINCT login` and `GROUP BY login HAVING count(*) > 1`. But you should really make this a new question and post the table structure if you want to get a worked out answer.